# Why the code is not taking all the inputs?

Tags: arrays, c

I want to write a code in C for 'Given an array and a number x. Find out if x lies in the array or not.
The code I tried is below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n, a[n], x, flag = 0;
    printf("Enter no. of elements: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("Enter x: ");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    printf("Enter elements: \n");
    for (int i = 0; i <= n - 1; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= n - 1; i++)
    {
        if (x == a[i])
        {
            flag = 1;
        }
    }
    if (flag == 1)
        printf("Found");
    return 0;
}
```

But the code is not giving the output which i was expecting.
[The output which i am getting say for n=6 & x=2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e24MZ.png)
Why it is taking only 4 inputs while n=6. Also, for other values of n it is producing some ambiguities.
So, I am not understanding why the code is giving such output ?

Comment: You appear to be trying to declare an int array of size `n` and then change the array's size.  That won't work.  A C array's size cannot be changed ... like that.

Comment: Change `a[n]` to `a[100]`, and then make sure you enter a number less than 100 for `n`.

Comment: Aside: the common way to write the loop is `for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)`. The loop `for (int i = 0; i <= n - 1; i++)` does exactly the same thing, but will get you into trouble with any experienced C programmer that has to work with your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you're declaring `a[n]` before `n` has a value. **After** `n` is given a value, you can declare the array `int a[n];`. That should solve your problem.

Comment: While this answer is technically correct, it doesn't explain *why* the loop for reading array elements terminates early. Do you know why?

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica because the program invokes undefined behavior. There is no point looking for why it fails in the way it does

Comment: @Snambo you should probably add that the variable length array declaration uses an uninitialized variable `n`, which causes all the problems.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya, so the answer should cite "undefined behaviour", and perhaps go some more in deep. Undefined behaviour is too many times used as a catch-all anyway but, at minimum, it should be cited.

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica
"While this answer is technically correct, it doesn't explain why the loop for reading array elements terminates early."<br>
`a[undefined-size-more-likely-0]` is located in stack, then at the step #i (4 in the attached picture) writing `a[i]` the variable `n` in stack was overwitten and the overwritten value is less than `i`, false of `i<n-1` caused `for-loop` to finish

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i <= n - 1; i++) {
    scanf("%d", &a[i]);
}
```

Assuming that "n" has a certain value, and seeing the simplicity of the loop (ie. for() ), what can cause "n" to change value while looping?

Hint: put a printf("Now n=%d\n", n) before that loop, and one after, and maybe another just after the scanf()... you should discover something interesting.